# Identifying views on UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am building an app that has a Scroll View with an image. On top of that I am adding views based on my custom class. Imagine a scroll UI view picture with pins on it. Background picture and then each pin is a new layer.

Something like this (not full code but pretty comprehensive will give you a good view of what I am trying to do.)

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var scrollView : UIScrollView!
    var imageView : UIImageView!



       override func viewDidLoad() {

            create()
            super.viewDidLoad()

        }

    func create() {
          let dynamicUserPin = UserPin(userID: "UX2318afjk2-fa8hasd-hasdf-jada-fjasd", name: "Ric", posX: Int(1500), posY: Int(1800), pictureURL: "11056102_10100155919186355_3729750518855248330_n.jpg", direction: 1, colour: "Red", currentTrack: 33, lastTimeConnected: Date())
              dynamicUserPin.tag = 1000

         containerView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.viewTapped(_:))))


            imageView.addSubview(dynamicUserPin)

            containerView.addSubview(imageView)


            scrollView.addSubview(containerView)

            view.addSubview(scrollView)
    }
}
```

My issue is that I will have to find the views (UserPins) which are quite dynamic and will change over time. I could obviously find the user pins by iterating over the views. That is no problem. The issue is how I can do it without tags as that means keeping a mapping between my userIDs and tags which I am trying to avoid. How do I get to the details of the subview? I have created an extension to get the sub views:

```
extension UIView {
     func subviewsList() -> [UIView] {
          var subviews = self.subviews
          if subviews.count == 0 {
               return subviews + []
          }
          for v in subviews {
               subviews += v.subviewsList()

          }
          return subviews
     }
}
```

and my view class looks like this:

import UIKit

```
class UserPin: UIView {


    var userID : String?
    var name : String?
    var posX : Int?
    var posY : Int?
    var pictureURL : String?
    var direction : Int?
    var colour : String?
    var currentTrack : Int?
    var lastTimeConnected : Date?


    init(userID: String, name: String, posX: Int, posY: Int, pictureURL: String, direction: Int, colour: String, currentTrack : Int, lastTimeConnected : Date)
    {
        self.userID = userID
        self.name = name
        self.posX = posX
        self.posY = posY
        self.pictureURL = pictureURL
        self.direction = direction
        self.colour = colour
        self.currentTrack = currentTrack
        self.lastTimeConnected = lastTimeConnected

        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: posX, y: posY, width: 100, height: 100))
        print("finished init")
        self.addControls(userID, name: name, posX: posX, posY: posY,  pictureURL: pictureURL, direction: direction,  colour: colour,  currentTrack: currentTrack, lastTimeConnected: lastTimeConnected)
    }
```

So how do I get the userID of a view that I've added?

Comment: Why not create a collection of the "Pins" (an array)?  Then you can just add or remove from this collection anytime one gets added or removed.  Then you don't have to get them by the "subview" collection and determine if they are a pin or some other OS given view.

Comment: You're right and that is what I will be doing. The code does not really show that I know but imagine that the dynamicUserPin will be replaced by an array of pins and added to the view as subviews. I guess the question is how do I get to the view object again to get the user ID?

Comment: If you have an array of data that you turn into these "Pins" then why not have an array of "Pins" as well?  Then you can loop through the "Pins" and get the UserID directly from them.  I guess I'm not completely understanding the dilemma.

Comment: @Putz1103 Have the solution for you, since you have userID etc on every pin, you can just check the UIView userID against the array and remove the UIView from the superView and the equivalant data from the array.

Comment: Don't use the term "layer". Call them subviews. In iOS, views are backed by Core Animation layers (`CALayer` objects) so using the term layer causes confusion.

Comment: @Putz1103 how do I get to the view though? That is the bit that I am struggling. I have implemented the changes and can add the views correctly from the array onto the parent view. But when I want to update them how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `UIViewController` subclass should contain a mutable set called something like `mapPins`, declared like this:

```
var mapPins: Set
```

Whenever you create a new pin, insert it into that mutable set as well as adding it as a `subView`.

Then, if you need access to all the pins, just iterate over the contents of the `mapPins` set.

> I guess the question is how do I get to the view object again to get the user ID?
>
> How do I get to the pin by tapping on it?

There's a few ways to do this. I suggest making a `UITapGestureRecognizer` for each pin view. (Make the gesture recogniser at the same time you create the pin.)

Create a method for the tap recognisers to call on your `UIViewController` subclass:

```
func handleTapOnPin(_ recogniser: UITapGestureRecognizer?) {
    // a pin has been tapped on
}
```

Set the target of the gesture recogniser to the subclass, and the action to a selector for this method, like this: `#selector(self.handleTapOnPin(_:))`.

Inside that method, to get access to your pin, you can do `recognizer.view()`.

Comment: Ok, think I am starting to get there. So assuming I have a mutable array called mapPins or userPins... How do I get to the pin by tapping on it?

Comment: @user2091936 The cleanest way is to create a delegate inside your UIView and add one UITapGestureRecognizer in it. When you tap the UIView you just call back to the UIViewController with your delegate method. You must of course set the UIViewController as the delegate responder when you add each pin subview. pinView.delegate = self